# How to write modular JavaScript code (library)

Tags: javascript, html, modular

I've been working on this little snippet:

```js
var a;
var b;
var c;

function generateResult() {
    // Custom variables
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
    var b = document.getElementById("operator").value;
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);

    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);

    var calc = function(a, b, c) {
        var result;

        if (b == "+") {
            console.log("Now in sum");
            result = a + c;
            return result;
        }

        else if (b == "-") {
            console.log("Now in sub");
            result = a - c;
            return result;
        }

        else if (b == "/") {
            console.log("Now in div");
            result = a / c;
            return result;
        }

        else if (b == "*") {
            console.log("Now in tim");
            result = a * c;
            return result;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (calc(a, b, c));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    <h1>Calculator (basic)</h1><br><br>

    First input:<br>
    <input type="number" id="firstNumber"><br><br>

    <select id="operator">
        <option id="sum" value="+">+</option>
        <option id="sub" value="-">-</option>
        <option id="div" value="/">/</option>
        <option id="tim" value="*">*</option>
    </select><br><br>

    Second input:<br>
    <input type="number" id="secondNumber"><br><br>
</form>

<button onclick="generateResult()">=</button><br><br>

<h3 id="result"></h3>

</body>

<script src="script.js" defer></script>

</html>
```

I want this code to be modular so it can be implemented by everyone. Like this: http://semester4.nl/bounce/demo/

I've been working on learning some basic javascript. Someone suggested to me that I should try and write my code modular (even simple stuff like this). I've used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOfwp6VlnlM
No luck so far, can somebody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Modularity is a style of programming. You can achieve results even with non-modular code. If you want reusable code please look at JavaScript best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap this code in [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
(() => {
    // your code
})();
```

If you have many files, good idea will be use Webpack, that help you with work, with AMD or CommonJS.

Other option is use [ES Modules](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules), that should work without Webpack.